# Centralizer of a dense subgroup in a maximal subgroup of a reductive group

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, gn.general-topology, algebraic-groups, topological-groups

I am looking for a reference to the following statement
"Let $G$ be a reductive algebraic group and $K$ a maximal compact subgroup of $G$. If $H$ is a dense subgroup in $K$, then the centralizer of $H$ in $G$ is equal to the centralizer of $K$ in $G$ and they are equal to the center of $G$."
I have a proof but I think this is a known result, I can´t find a reference.

Comment: Do you mean real reductive group? compact subgroups also make sense in the $p$-adic case and are quite different. Also, I expect dense to be in the Hausdorff topology? (although, well, it seems it plays no role, as it's clear that the question just boils down to describe the centralizer of $K$)

Comment: Complex reductive group

Comment: In the complex case, every maximal compact subgroup is Zariski-dense, and the result follows.

Comment: Why it follows?

Comment: The centralizer of $H$ in $G$ is equal to the centralizer of $K$ in $G$ (because $H$ is dense in $K$), which is in turn is equal to the centralizer of of $G$ in $G$ (because $K$ is Zariski-dense in $G$, as @YCor has mentioned), that is, to the center of $G$. In general the center of $G$ is not equal to the centralizer of $H$ in $K$ (take $G=\mathbb{C}^*$ and let $H=K$ be the maxiamal compact subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^*$).

Comment: I made a mistake at the statement, i have corrected it. Thanks for your remarks.

Comment: Since $G$ is a connected reductive $\mathbf{C}$-group, and the centralizer of such an $H$ is certainly equal to that of the (connected) maximal compact subgroup $K$ of $G(\mathbf{C})$, by connectedness of $G(\mathbf{C})$ it suffices to show that ${\rm{Lie}}(K)$ spans ${\rm{Lie}}(G(\mathbf{C})) = {\rm{Lie}}(G)$ over $\mathbf{C}$.  In fact, even better the natural map $\mathbf{C} \otimes_{\mathbf{R}} {\rm{Lie}}(K) \rightarrow {\rm{Lie}}(G)$ is an isomorphism.  Indeed, $K = G_0(\mathbf{R})$ for a unique connected anisotropic reductive $\mathbf{R}$-group $G_0$,  and $G \simeq (G_0)_{\mathbf{C}}$!

Comment: And the part "If K is Zariski-dense subgroup of G, then the centralizer of K in G is the center of G", is there any reference to this fact?

Comment: The centralizer of an element is a Zariski closed subgroup. Hence the centralizer of a subgroup, being the intersection of the element centralizers, is also algebraic. Then since the centralizer of $H$ is algebraically defined, it must centralize the Zariski closure of $H$. In your case $H=K$ and its Zariski closure is $G$.